# How can I reference the name of the file into which I'm inserting in my Code Snippet?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm writing a code snippet to insert a copyright header.  The basic snippet is no problem.  I'd like to be able to automatically reference the name of the file which I'm inserting the snippet in the text that is being inserted.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ClassName function demonstrated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242312%28VS.80%29.aspx). (Second example). If you need to add it outside the class scope, you could use [Snippet Designer](http://snippetdesigner.codeplex.com/) which is a plugin to make snippet creation easier.

Comment: Even though having one class/struct/interface/enum per file is good practice, this might not always be the case.

Comment: True. In addition our coding standard is that the copyright header must be placed at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Beside creating a snippet, you might consider creating a Template and putting the file name as a parameter ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa.aspx)).